# setInterval within React components and hot reloading (Webpack)

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, webpack-hmr

I would like to call a function repeatedly in a React component, from the time it mounts, until it unmounts, and make it work with webpack HMR (hot reloading).

Easiest way is to set an interval in componentDidMount as suggested in ReactJS docs: [1]: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

```
componentDidMount () {
  const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
  setInterval(() => console.log('Component ' + number.toString()), 5000)
}
```

I have searched but can't find a solution to clear the interval before webpack HMR calls componentDidMount for our updated component. This means we have an new interval every time the module hot reloads.

Note: `componentWillUnmount` is not called before Webpack rebundles

UPDATE: Rebundling should call `componentWillUnmount` when HMR is properly set

What is the best way to achieve repeated delayed function calls with webpack HMR ?

Comment: componentWillUnmount

Comment: The problem is that `componentWillUnmount` is not called before webpack rebundles.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just figured out the problem was coming from my webpack HMR implementation, which was not explicitly unmounting hot routes.

You may want to check this commit if you happen to have the same issue, take a look at the src/main.js diff file:
https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/commit/a602625b20ade172c829b583882ae44c150e738c